# Using Urllib with Scrapy for Pagination

Tags: python, scrapy, python-requests, urllib, python-3.5

Trying to Scrap Next Page with Scrapy, Python 3.5 using urlib python library

```
    import datetime
    import urllib.request
    import urllib.error
    import urllib.parse
    import socket
    import scrapy
    from scrapy.loader.processors import MapCompose, Join
    from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
    from properties.items import PropertiesItem


    class BasicSpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "manual"
        allowed_domains = ["web"]

        # Start on the first index page
        start_urls = (
            'http://scrapybook.s3.amazonaws.com/properties/index_00000.html',
        )

        def parse(self, response):
            # Get the next index URLs and yield Requests
            next_selector = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class,"next")]//@href')
            for url in next_selector.extract():
                yield Request(urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, url))

            # Get item URLs and yield Requests
            item_selector = response.xpath('//*[@itemprop="url"]/@href')
            for url in item_selector.extract():
                yield Request(urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse_item)


        def parse(self, response):
            l = ItemLoader(item=PropertiesItem(), response=response)
            l.add_xpath('title', '//*[@itemprop="name"]/text()')
            return l.load_item()
```

Everything Works Just Fine Without Error, But Scrapy Fetching only First Page, but according to code it should fetch all Next Pages

Here is the Output

```
[{
    "title": [
      "bermondsey ec kennington drive acton seven rm",
    .......
      "mary conversion borders eastham with gas"
  }]

// Only Page 0 Titles :(
```

Is anything Wrong with Request or Urllib Call Syntax ?

PS : Xpath working, Scrapy Shell 'URL'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's Start with Wrong Uses Of **Python Packages**

1. Using **Request** without importing it, Fix it by.

   **from scrapy import Request**
2. Wrong use of **urljoin class from urllib**, first import it

   **from urllib.parse import urljoin**

   now use `urljoin` direct without calling **`urllib.parse.urljoin`**

   change it on

   yield Request(urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, url))
   yield Request(urllib.parse.urljoin(response.url, url), callback=self.parse_item)
3. Not calling **`parse_item`**

   call it on

   def parse(self, response): #replace parse to parse_item

PS : If this code, is from Learning Scrapy Book then here is complete git example for **python3** Version

https://github.com/Rahulsharma0810/Scrapy-Pagination-URLJOIN-Example

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have two `parse` functions. So you only have the second one since it overrides the first one.

Just rename the second one to `parse_item` like the rest of your code seems to indicate.